# laravel validation using required with

Tags: php, laravel

I have three checkboxes array like `cash`, `cheque` and `bank`.

When I click on bank checkbox it shows two text box.
Suppose I click on `bank` check box then it will show two text box and now I submit the form .

How can I validate this two text box using required_with laravel validaton.

Comment: if you can just show us what you have tried so far ?

Comment: You can use "sometimes" like this:
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
]);


https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: Format variable and added some line breaks for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

'payment-type' is I set required(It's your choice) and next validation if payment type value is 2 then 'other-type' is required.

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
  'payment-type' => 'required',
  'other-type' => 'required_if:payment-type, 2'
], $messages);
return $validator;
```